# Notification bar to web page similar to the SO

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How do I write a notification bar in JavaScript similar to the one that you see on Stack Overflow?

In my project they are asking for one just the same as this website 
I wrote the code for this for this but I am not getting the exact one .,

I want to know about the cookie logic and vertical slidiing and fadeout and any modifications in the code.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a jquery plugin to do exactly what you are talking about:  http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/10/29/jbar-a-jquery-notification-plugin/

Comment: This plugin seems to only be intended to trigger notifications based on an element click event (i.e. $(ElementYouWillBeClicking).bar(...); )  It would make more sense if the $(Element) you call bar() on was a initially hidden div.